# Deploy an ASP NET Core Application which connect to RavenDB

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, ravendb, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to deploy a **.NET Core application** to Azure which connects to **RavenDB**, locally there is no problem, since it requires a certificate to be installed and read at the time of connection initialization, the problem is that when it is in the cloud, it shows me this error:

```
The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. -> The credentials supplied to the 
package were not recognized (The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
```

I can't find a way to solve it, I include the certificate in the production version, also install the certifcate from the App Service Azure control panel. I really would like to know how to fix this, i didn't find a solution when i searched in other places

Comment: Can you share the piece of code which reads the certificate?

Answer (score 0):

How do you load the client certificate in your application?
Try using the machine keyset flag.

`[DocumentStore].Certificate = new X509Certificate2("[client cert path]", (string)null, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);`